# What is the vision on Zoos according to Islam?

Tags: animals

What is the view of Islam on Zoos, Aquariums and similar places?

Can we go there or looking at suffering will be taking as a sin?

Comment: It is of course wrong (discouraged, although I doubt if it would also be forbidden) unless there is a justifiable benefit in it. Hunting the animals is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the full fatwa here:
http://islamqa.info/en/ref/1608

Basically, going to the zoo is fine based on the initial conclusion from the fatwa linked above:

> On the basis of the opinion that it is permissible to keep animals in
>   cages, visiting places designed for the purpose of displaying these
>   animals to the public such as those known nowadays as zoos, for the
>   purpose of enjoying looking at the different types of animals, is
>   permissible.

Because of this part of the quran:

> “Do they not look in the dominion of the heavens and the earth and all
>   things that Allaah has created…?” [al-A’raaf 7:185].

And this hadith:

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Think
>   about the signs of Allaah, do not think about Allaah.” (Reported by
>   al-Bayhaqi in al-Shu’ab, 1/136 and by al-Laalakaa’i in al-Sunnah,
>   3/525. See al-Saheehah, 4/395).

Answer (score -1):

It's haram to go to any place where animals are being kept prisoners and away from the natural life. It's a vile evil act and should be obvious through out the Quran animals are treated very highly. With the Internet anyone can see any animal in great detail if there that curious. It makes me really sad as muslim how ignorant we are about such things. But now if you go online and search animal cruelty in zoo's it's eye opening. I used to love the zoo because I love animals. It didn't even cross my mind about the ethics. After watching a documentary it opened my eyes. Then just doing my own research made me realise how blindly we accept all of societies acts. Please don't go and tell others not to.

Comment: This post could use some evidences to support your claims!